# How to show wholesale_price in invoice on prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, invoice

I have a question...
How to to show wholesale_price for custommer on prestashop invoice. 
My code in classes/product.php

```
$query = "SELECT wholesale_price FROM ps_product WHERE id_product =   '$id_product' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if ($reduction_from_category !== false)
            $price -= $price * (float)$reduction_from_category;
            elseif ($id_group == 12)

            $price -= ($price - $row[0]);

    }
```

Price show in products but no in invoice.
In invoice product price shows 0.00
Please help